# error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope

Tags: android, macos, android-source, android-build

**I am new to android build system ,I am getting following error while building in MAC OS. Please help me out to make build success.**

```
In file included from external/libcxx/src/any.cpp:10:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/experimental/any:84:

external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:167:44: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long      abs(     long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return  labs(__x);}
                                           ^

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:115:44: note: target of using declaration

inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long      abs(     long __x) _NOEXCEPT 

{return  labs(__x);}
                                           ^

external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:135:9: note: using declaration

using ::abs;
        ^

external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:169:44: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long long abs(long long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return llabs(__x);}
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:117:44: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long long abs(long long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return llabs(__x);}
                                           ^
external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:135:9: note: using declaration
using ::abs;
        ^
external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:172:42: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY  ldiv_t div(     long __x,      long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return  ldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:120:42: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY  ldiv_t div(     long __x,      long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return  ldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:143:9: note: using declaration
using ::div;
        ^
external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:174:42: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x, long long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return lldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:122:42: note: target of using declaration

inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x, long long 

__y) _NOEXCEPT {return lldiv(__x, __y);}

                                         ^

external/libcxx/include/cstdlib:143:9: note: using declaration
using ::div;
        ^

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

20 errors generated.


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. It seems there's a bug in Xcode 9's llvm compiler: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87814

I solved the problem by:

- removing xcode 9: https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos
- downloading and installing xcode 8.3.3 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: what if I can't install Xcode 8.3.3? As I have a newer MacOSX(Big sur) and it's not compatible with Xcode8.3.3

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed it removing and download Android NDK. After then I tried to make build many times. Because Mac OS blocking to download some additional files, you must allow it in "Security & Privacy" and start build again